# Visual Composer for Prestashop problem with loading scripts

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, visual-composer

I'm working on Prestashop with Visual Composer and have some weird problem. VC Content Anywhere stop working one day (no one except me haven't got admin access, so no changes was made).

Console errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.widget is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: a.widget is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: $.widget is not a function
```

etc.

But scripts are in html code, and they are not broken.

Do you know what it could be?

Comment: looks like you got an error with jquery-ui.js, first look if it's loaded well

Comment: @Melvita I know it's problem with jquery ui and some modules are loaded well and some don't load. On other pages at BO all jquery ui modules are loaded. 

All modules are properly linked in head section, links aren't broken. I don't know why some of jquery modules don't load and how to check it.